# How to return json with 2 objects using asp.net core framework?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net

How to return 2 objects through Json ? 
I am building a tag input field from Telerik and I want to pass string values from 2 tables namely, "Skills" and "Expertises" to a tag jquery control.

```
 public JsonResult Skills_Read(string text)
    {
        var result = GetSkills();
        var result1 = GetExpertises();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            result = result.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(text)).ToList();
            result1 = result1.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(text)).ToList();

        }

        return Json(result);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Skill> GetSkills()
    {
        var result = _context.Skills;

        return result;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Expertise> GetExpertises()
    {
        var result = _context.Expertises;

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What error are you facing ?

Comment: What is your expected json string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new object.

```
public JsonResult Skills_Read(string text)
{
    var result = GetSkills();
    var result1 = GetExpertises();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        result = result.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(text)).ToList();
        result1 = result1.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(text)).ToList();

    }

    return Json(new { result, result1 });
}
```

Also

`return Json(new { Skills = result, Expertises = result1 })`

**Update Working Code I Just span up**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    class One
    {
        public string Word { get; set; }
    }

    class Two
    {
        public string Word { get; set; }
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        return new JsonResult(new {
            First = new One { Word = "Some Word" },
            Second = new Two { Word = "Another Word" }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: Result]

Comment: Can I return one Json containing both objects ? as I'm using telerik control  and it couldn't read your current way of returning Json.